Render control conditionally either with or without parent wrapper tags, without duplicated code
In a React component I need to render a Select conditionally in the following way:

If a certain prop exists, Select is wrapped in a parent tag structure of <div><Form>..</Form></div>
Otherwise the Select is not wrapped in these parent tags.

Obviously I can do ? : duplication which redefines the Select as
{props.flag
 ?
    <div className="formField">
        <Form error={props.error}>
            <Select...> 
            {/* Huge Select with lots of definitions */}
        </Form>
    </div>
 :
    <Select...> 
    {/* Huge Select with lots of definitions */}

But I don't want to duplicate that huge Select snippet. Is there a way to isolate a snippet and quickly plug it in as appropriate, without factoring out the Select as a new component?

you can define <Select...>  as a one component.

I just don't want to introduce extra components.

code sandbox example toggling a wrapper.  https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/misty-glade-mnnsrg?file=%2Fsrc%2F_app.js
how about using a higher order function with children?
const withConditionalWrapper = (condition, wrapper, content) =>
  condition ? wrapper(content) : content;

then put that use that function to conditionally wrap a parent around your select.
   {withConditionalWrapper(
        shouldWrap,
        (children) => (
          <div
            style={{
              border: "2px solid blue",
              padding: "20px",
              backgroundColor: "red",
            }}
          >
            {children}
          </div>
        ),
        <select>
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
        </select>
      )}

